# Python packages are located in differente location

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pip

- I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which comes python 3.8.
- I installed python3.9 and made it as default python `update-alternatives`
- under /usr/bin/ I have python2.7/ python3/ python3.8/ and python3.9/

==> Now the problem that I am facing is when I installed sqlalchemy using `pip install sqlalchemy` its version was 1.3.12, which has a compatibility problem with pandas because it requires version '1.4.0'.

`>>>pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy`

```
>>> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.3.12)
Collecting sqlalchemy
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.4.31-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/1.6 MB 8.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17
  Downloading greenlet-1.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (156 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 156.6/156.6 KB 9.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: greenlet, sqlalchemy
Successfully installed greenlet-1.1.2 sqlalchemy-1.4.31
```

I wrote the same command again it gave me this :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.4.31)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqlalchemy) (1.1.2)
```

I also did this to check:

`>>>pip show sqlalchemy | grep Location`

`>>>Location: /home/Moe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

but when I import sqlalchemy in a script it still uses the old version
it seems that the new version is installed in a different location

`>>> print(sqlalchemy.__file__)`

`>>>/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py`

Can Someone please explain this to me, and if possible explain the entire package management problem here

Comment: Would be better to use virtual environments with virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv or anyting. `pip install virtualenv`, then create a virtualenv `python3.8 -m virtualenv .venv` and activate it before installing packages inside : `source .venv/bin/activate`. (also, `-p` option of virtualenv can be use to specify a python version / path to use.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `pip` that is associated with your python 3.8, you can see that in the whl file that is downloaded:

```
Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.4.31-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

Note the **cp38**

And in the output of running the install again:

```
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.4.31)
```

Note the **python3.8**.

Since you have mentioned that you downloaded python 3.9, you are probably running your scripts using that version of python. You will need to use the pip that is associated with that python. If you are running your script with

```
python <scriptfile>
```

Then you should `pip install` with

```
python -m pip install ...
```